# Asunto con el Checkbox

Tags: html, html5, bootstrap, checkbox

buen día a todos, lo que deseo hacer creo que es algo sencillo pero no doy con la respuesta, estoy intentando hacer un formulario y necesito ubicar los checkbox a la derecha y las opciones a la izquierda.

[image: Ejemplo de como debe ser]

este es un ejemplo en bootstrap. ¿como debería codificarlo para que me quede igual al de la imagen?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="/lib/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<h2>Form control: checkbox</h2>
<p>The form below contains three checkboxes. The last option is disabled: 
</p>
<form role="form">
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 1</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 2</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 3</label>
</div>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

De ante mano, agradesco toda la ayuda que me puedan brindar. saludos.

Comment: separa label e input y luego le das a cada uno el css que quieras <label>Option 1</label> <input type="checkbox" value="">, no tiene que ir el input dentro del label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tan sencillo como sacar los inputs de los labels

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="/lib/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<h2>Form control: checkbox</h2>
<p>The form below contains three checkboxes. The last option is disabled: 
</p>
<form role="form">
<div class="checkbox">
  <label class="col-md-6" for="check1">opcion 1</label>
  <input class="col-md-6" type="checkbox" name="check1" value="">
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label class="col-md-6" for="check2">opcion 2</label>
  <input class="col-md-6" type="checkbox" name="check2" value="">
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label class="col-md-6" for="check3">opcion 3</label>
   <input class="col-md-6" type="checkbox" name="check3" value="">
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A mi me funcionó:

```
input[type=checkbox]
{   
   display: inline !important;
}
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica qué hace esta línea de código. Lee [answer].

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar lo que son las grillas esta en la documentaciond e bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/ y por ejemplo en toda tu pantalla mide 12 y eso lo puedes dividir en varias partes para que te de el resultado por ejemplo asi

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="/lib/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<h2>Form control: checkbox</h2>
<p>The form below contains three checkboxes. The last option is disabled:</p>
<form class="col-md-12">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-6" for="">opcion 1</label>
<input class="col-md-6" type="checkbox" name="check1" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-6" for="">opcion 2</label>
<input class="col-md-6" type="checkbox" name="check1" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-6" for="">opcion 3</label>
<input class="col-md-6" type="checkbox" name="check1" value="">
</div>

</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

solo tienes que darle un poco mas de estilos...